# Very slow display of folder contents

Tags: windows-11

I have a particular folder named "Movies", which contains about 150 items, which take a long time to display (Windows 11). And this, whatever the display mode (list, icons, details...).

If I change the name of the folder, the content display is fast again. If I rename the folder to "Movies" again, the display becomes slow again.

I tried to clean the folder history. The same.

Do I need to reformat my drive, change CPU, change ISP, and move to another solar system, or is there another simpler solution to this problem?

Comment: I hear Aldebaran is pretty nice this time of year... :-D Interesting issue. What's the full path of the folder? If you have space, rename the folder to "Movs", create a new folder "Movies" in the same location and copy the contents of "Movs" - does the problem appear in the new "Movies"?

Comment: Try in Explorer to set in View pane the viewing mode to Details. Is the loading still slow?

Answer (score 3):

Check the property tab of the folder in windows exlorer. There is a tab called "customize".

There is a setting titled "optimize this folder for" followed by a selector element. If this is not set to "general elements" try out this setting.

I noticed the same problem comparing the speed of listing folders under Windows XP and Windows 7.
The recipe above solved my problem.

Comment: "Fit"-->"Customize"